# Prove $ ∀a, b, c ∈ Z,$ if $ab + ac ≡ 3$ (mod 6) then b $\not\equiv$ c (mod 6).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove $∀a, b, c ∈ Z,$ if $ab + ac ≡ 3$ (mod 6) then b $\not\equiv$ c (mod 6).

New to proof work and my problem is I have some general feelings about this problem but don't know how to express it since I'm not familiar enough with modular arithmetic theory.

I've moved forward using the contrapositve to work with.

Prove $∀a, b, c ∈ Z,$  if b $\equiv$ c (mod 6). Then $ab + ac \not\equiv 3$ (mod 6)

I know congruent integers b and c imply $\frac{b-c}{6}$ being perfectly divisible and I know multiplying a same constant $a$ to both numbers does not change their congruence *before* summing them.

Basically, I'm stuck here. I *think* that $ab + ac \not\equiv 3$ (mod 6) is true because I *think* congruent integers $b$ and $c$ multiplied by a same constant $a$ can only take an answer of 0, 1 and 2 in the equation $ab + ac$(mod 6).

Obviously, me *thinking* things is not very mathematical! Plus I have a strong feeling I'm just flat out wrong somewhere, any ideas or solutions towards proving this statement would be very much stuided and appreciated. :)

Comment: $ab+ac\equiv2ab$ if $b\equiv c\pmod6$ surely?

Comment: What Lord Shark is saying that if $b\equiv c$, then $ab+ac$ is an **even** integer :-)

Comment: And an even integer will always result in an even or 0 result in terms of $ab+ac$ (mod 6) and explicitly not result in an answer of 3 like $3$ (mod 6) does. Hmm I feel like the answer is in front of me lol! I'll try and take this somewhere in a proof.

Comment: It seems like this is incredibly simple (now) or I'm missing something. If two integers are congruent then their product with a constant summed is always even as you lovely people have pointed out. An even integer cannot be congruent with 3 (mod 6). Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for a contradiction that $$ab+ac\equiv3\pmod6$$ and $$b\equiv c\pmod6.$$
Then
$$2ab\equiv ab+ac\equiv3\pmod6,$$
$$3\cdot2ab\equiv3\cdot3\pmod6,$$
$$0\equiv3\pmod6,$$
which is absurd.